# How do I add sub directory of directory as a git submodule?

Tags: git, github, git-submodules, mediawiki-extensions

I'm trying to add a submodule, as I normally would do, I did:

```
git submodule add -f -b master 'https://github.com/OrganicDesign/extensions/tree/master/MediaWiki/PdfBook/'
```

Only it gives me

```
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/OrganicDesign/extensions/MediaWiki/PdfBook/' not found since it does not recognize this as a git repository.
```

Is there anyway to add this submodule (without having to fork anything; so I can keep the upstream)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way [`git submodule`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) works is that you have to provide it a *root* link for the repo you want to add.

Fro instance:

```
git submodule add -f -b master https://github.com/OrganicDesign/extensions.git
```

If you want to access files and directories down the repository tree you would have to do it locally.

Comment: Thank you. The problem is I really don't want anything else from the root repo (quite a lot of things) and I only need that specific part of it.

Comment: What you are looking for is a mixture of sub-modules and [sparse checkouts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13738951/4000674). The latter is the way of cloning only a sub-directory of a repo.  I don't know if `git` provides a way of doing that with a single command, but it can be done either manually or automated with a script.